# Sharepoint 2010 - Workflow, return field as Lookup Values, Comma Delimited getting both lookup id and lookup value

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow, lookup-column

I'm working on a simple workflow in SPD 2010 which is going to send an email to multiple recipients based on lookup values and even though I set the "Return Field As Lookup Values, Comma Delimited" I'm still getting the lookup id just after the lookup value like this:

`someone@email.com;#23` -> everything works fine though, the recipient gets the email

If the workflow will add 2 lookup values the field looks like this:

`someone@email.com;#23;someone2@email.com;#24` -> end result in nothing, the workflow gets canceled.

Is there a way to get rid of the lookup id?

EDIT:
The value I'm retrieving with the lookup are "email addresses, semicolon delimited"

I've tried to create a local variable to store the lookup values (in order to return it as "email addresses, semicolon delimited", but when I set the variable value to the lookup value I can only return it as "String", "Lookup Value, comma delimited" and "Lookup Ids, comma delimited" which makes the local variable unable to return it as the intended type.

I'm getting a "coercion failed" error.

Comment: So, I take it the lookup is multi-choice lookup based on your example. Is the lookup also getting the ID as well? The problem I see is that it is not using commas to separate, but semicolons which doesn't help for using string functions. Is there not a place to actually select the separator?

Comment: I'm getting the ID at the end of the lookup value. Seems that at some point its being converted to Text and showing the lookup ID. Now I'm wondering if I just change the delimiter for those email adresses manually, will that solve the problem.

Comment: I have tested your case, and everethyng works fine with "Return Field As: Lookup Values, Comma Delimited" in "To" Field. How have got the actual value passed to email activity?

Comment: I'm adding the value by "Workflow Lookup for a User".

Comment: Maybe this will help. 1 lookup value may have 1 or 2 email addresses which are going to be semicolon delimited, if the workflow adds 2 lookup values the returned values are like this: 'someone1@email.com;someone2@email.com;#45;someone3@email.com;someone4@email.com;#46'

Comment: @spevilgenius I tried

Comment: Yes, you may need to use the string functions to make this work. Do you have the workflow extensions for SPD available? Unfortunately this is a solution (.wsp) that needs to get deployed, but it gives you better string functions. I don't remember what functions are available out of the box anymore :) Not sure what easy avenue there is here...

Comment: Weird thing happened. I manually put the info in the field which is going to be looked up separating emails with commas and did the workflow from scratch and it works

Comment: is the issue resolved or pending ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
Return as email id semicolon delimited
```

That way there would be no lookup id.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, solution is just create a new `SPFieldLookupValue` and read `LookupValue` property. It's quite simple, but can save some time for others.

```
public String LinkTitleCode
{
    get
    {
        var lookupText = Get<String>("LinkTitleCode");
        return new SPFieldLookupValue(lookupText).LookupValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, got `"ID# Lookup text"` returned from workflow.

The workflow was set to return field as `"String"`. I changed it to `"Lookup Value (as text)"` and it worked.